# Existence of intermediate subgroups and representations theory.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $V$ an irreducible representation, $H$ a subgroup.
Let $V^H$ be the subspace of vectors of $V$ invariant under the action of $H$.

Suppose that $dim(V^H)>1$.
Then $dim(V) > 1 $ and $dim(V^G)=0$.

> **Question**: Is there an intermediate subgroup $H \subset P \subset G$  such that $dim(V^P)=1$ ?

Comment: Reminds me of the Artin-Brauer theorem(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. A counterexample is the $2$-dimensional irreducible complex representation of $G=Q_8$ with $H=1$.

Comment: Thank you ! [Here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Faithful_irreducible_representation_of_quaternion_group) is a description of this representation, and [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_quaternion_group), the subgroups of $Q_8$. The result follows by the fact that every non-trivial subgroup contain the element -1.