# Is there a transitive permutation group satisfying these properties?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, permutations, gap

Let $G \subset S_n$ be a transitive permutation group and let $H=G_1:=\{ g \in G  \ \vert \ g(1)=1 \}$.
Let $(K_i)_{i \in I}$ be the sequence of minimal overgroups of $H$ in $G$.
Note that if $G$ is primitive, then the sequence above is reduced to $G$ alone.

Let the following properties:

1. There are two distinct irreducible representations $V$ and $W$ of $G$ such that $dim(V^H)$ and $dim(W^H) \ge 2$.
2. $\sum_{i \in I} [G : K_i] > [G:H]$ $ (= n)$.
3. The lattice of intermediate subgroups $\mathcal{L}(H \subset G)$ is distributive.

*Question*: Is there a transitive group satisfying ($1$), ($2$) and ($3$)?
If yes, what are the first examples?
Or anyway, what's your better lower bound for $n$?

*Remark*: Thanks to a GAP computation, the answer is no for $n \le 17$.
 So my better lower bound is $n \ge 18$.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) in $K_i$ "be the sequence of maximal subgroups", do you mean just a set of maximal subgroups? 2) If it is reduced for $H$ alone when $G$ is primitive, then (2) can not hold for primitive groups?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: 1) I mean the set of all the maximal subgroups of $G$ containing $H$. 2) Yes.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I've corrected the post, $(K_i)$ is **not** the set of all the maximal subgroups of $G$ containing $H$, but the set of all the minimal overgroups of $H$ in $G$. The inequality 2. is consequently modified.

Comment: About my lower bound, it's ok because for $n \le 17$, there is no transitive group satisfying 1. and 3.

Comment: Have you managed to go beyond n=17 so far?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: in fact with GAP we can't do beyond index $30$, and this question is close to (but not the same)  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/684172/84284 , which admits a first known counter-example ($D_{12} \subset L_2(11)$) of index $55$. This counter-example does not work here because it is maximal and so does not check (2), nevertheless, to focus on simple groups seems to be a good strategy.